# Python printing form sequence

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm looking to print from a sequence from the first instance of a character in python 3.4.

This is what I'm looking to illustrate:

`From( "c", "fghechjue" )` =>

```
c
h
j
u
e
```

I'm trying to get it using for, but having trouble.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? This shuld be pretty basic.

Comment: Thanks, but the idea is that the programming will read something like From ( c, s ). I have been working on this for hours and am getting nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

Use slicing notation:

```
>>> s = "fghechjue"
>>> s[s.index('c'):]
'chjue'
```

[`str.index()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.index) will return the position of the first instance of the letter given. In this case, it will return 4. Then we do `s[4:]`, which slices everything after the fifth letter.

---

If you wanted this as a function:

```
def from(letter, s):
    return s[s.index(letter):]

from('c', 'fghechjue')
```

Comment: OP wants add some `\n` between the `'chjue'` ;)

Comment: @KevinGuan It's very hard to tell from the formatting of his original revision. I will wait for OP to respond

Comment: Yeah, however I know it.